# Position of last-visited page

Tags: html, scroll, browser-history

How does websites like Facebook or Stackoverflow remember the position I was at when I navigate away from their site to another site and hit the "Back" button on my browser?

Answer (score 1):

It's not the website, it is the browser. If you have used ID's in your code, the browser will remember approximately which one you were at when you clicked a link.